# PHP dynamic search

Tags: php, mongodb, dynamic

I want to display images from my database as long as I am typing something in textfield (this should be dynamic, when I erase character more matching results should appear). I was thinking about something like this but it doesnt work 
**Form**
`<form>
        Wpisz wyszukiwaną frazę: <br />
        <input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value)"/>
        </form>`

 **and Function**

```
function search($str) {


$db =get_db();
if ($db){
    if ($str !== "") {
        $images=$db->images->find();
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $name=$image['name'];
            if (stristr($image['title'], $str)) {
                echo '<br />'.'<a href="images/watermark/'.$name.'"'.' target="_blank">'.'<img src="images/small/'.$name.'"'.' alt="error">'.'</a>';
            }

        }
    }
}

}
```

I'm using mongodb if it changes anything, `get_db()` connects to database. How to make this work?

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: acctualy I've figured it out, I didn't include script code in html head, now everything works fine